# What type of naval ship is this?

Tags: identification, naval, ships, nautical

What type of naval ship is this? Note gun batteries on stern, Unknown location and date.[image: Black and white image of a ship. Photo is taken from the waterline.]

Comment: I've edited the image you posted into the question rather than the answer. Please also let us know anything else about the photo that you have information on, as well as things you are sure it's *not* because you've already checked. This will save people time because it helps them avoid retracing your steps.

Comment: Judging from the other ship in the photo, must be at least 1950.

Answer (score 13):

After some looking at Armed Merchant Cruisers, I believe instead that this is USS Vulcan ([AR-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Vulcan_(AR-5))), a Vulcan-class repair ship.
A better picture can be found at [Navsource.org](https://www.navsource.org/archives/09/25/09250514.jpg) showing the rear gun turrets much better.

The picture from Navsource shows:

[image]

where you can clearly see the rear turrets, and the cranes astride the rear funnel.

Vulcan was in service from 1941 to 1992.